# Magento Installation Issue (Install Not Being Found)

Tags: magento, hyperlink, installation

I am currently trying to install the latest version of Magento on a virtual machine running the latest version of Ubuntu Server. Ubuntu has been correctly setup with Nginx and PhpMyAdmin. The problem I'm running into is to do with the installation of Magento itself. I have the magento CMS in a /magento/ folder under the root directory of my sites folder "magento.dev" but when I go to install the CMS by entering "http://magento.dev/magento" I get redirected to "http://magento.dev/magento/index.php/install/" which I take is normal and shows the rewrites are working but the problem is I get a link appears to be broken error. I have also tried "http://magento.dev/magento/install.php" and several others but no luck.

I have edited the .htaccess to reflect magentos root folder by un-commenting "RewriteBase /magento/".

I have searched extensively for fixes to this issue but havnt really found anything of much use as of yet.

Hopefully you guys might be able to help me out.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax for nginx configuration is different(but more clean) than apache.

you probably might be using apache2's configuration for nginx

PS : nginx configuration files are generally /etc/nginx/sites-available/websitename

look at this question, it might help you. https://serverfault.com/questions/24243/nginx-support-for-htaccess-rewrite-rules-differences-from-apache